# Visual Studio without localdb

Tags: visual-studio

I'm installing VS 2022 Enterprise and I don’t need localdb and SQL Server Express because I have a cloud SQL, so I just use the SQL Server Management Studio interface.

When I unchecked the local db option, the VS Installer also unchecked ASP.NET and many more options.

I think I have to uncheck localdb and mark all others pre-requirements like ASP.NET so I can get those things to work properly.

Can someone confirm this?

Localdb uses some resources that if I have cloud I don’t need them, I think it will install SQL Server Express.